# Why is my Raspberry Pi 3 endlessly rebooting?

Tags: pi-3, hardware, openelec

I have a RPi 3 with OpenELEC for more than a year. Last week it suddenly started to endlessly reboot a few times per minute, even if I leave it on the main (home) KODI screen.
My RPi uses the original RPi Power Supply and was plugged in for all the time.

What could be the reason for the sudden endless reboot?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the power supply is failing to output 4.5v and less than the needed amperage. If you have another power supply, I would try that.

Comment: No. Unfortunately I don't have another Power Supply around. Couldn't it be the RPi 3 board ? Or, maybe OpenELEC issue ?

Comment: let's say, it is the Power Supply, then maybe you know how to check this thoroughly ?